# Get a text box to pop up Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to get a text box to pop up on an event. I have an uber like django app, a customer can be looking for someone to provide a service. Once someone 'claims' this customer (ie they are going to provide the service) I want a text box to pop up on their screen saying "Someone is on their way." So basically there is a BooleanField 'active' in the database, `True` when the customer is looking for a service and `False` they are not. When a customer is claimed this sets `active` to false. Is there a way based to trigger a textbox in the customer view when that happens, can I use JQuery, Ajax, is this an example of where a django 'signal'  would come in handy, etc ?

Comment: Please provide some code. To give you a hint in the right direction: When  User B accepts the request of User A he probably has to click a button or fill out a form. In the  validation of that action you could send a `Django signal`. If you never worked with them you could use a package like notify which takes care of that.

Comment: hansTheFranz, i ran pip install notify and it downloaded, do you happen to know where i can learn how to use notify?

Comment: https://github.com/v1k45/django-notify-x#sending-notifications-to-a-single-user usually you find documentations on the GitHub repo or google "packagename Django docs/read the docs"

Comment: did you achieve your goal?